# Objective C Segmentation Fault when using "NO" value in NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

Why do I get a Segmentation Fault when using a NO value in an NSDictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only put instances of objects in a dictionary, set or array.
Primitive types are not allowed, hence the segmentation fault.

Use a NSNumber instead:

```
[ dict setObject: [ NSNumber numberWithBool: yourBool ] forKey: @"..." ];
```

Comment: Apparently the BOOL macro expansion is not object aware (needless to say).